# Wrapping data cable around ferrite rod

Tags: communication, emc

I am trying to do some high quality audio recording using a fire wire interface.  Currently I have a naked firewire cable.  I was looking on eBay for some ferrite cores and that got me thinking about wrapping the wire around a ferrite rod.

If I were to wrap a data cable, such as firewire, around a ferrite rod I would think that that would take away almost all of the capacitance in the cable as well as prevent any interference.  Would I get a cleaner data connection if I did this?

Comment: You really need to proofread what you write before posting.

Comment: That was a serious autocorrect fail.

Comment: @KeeganMcCarthy  Why do you think that you need a common mode filter at all?  Do you have EMI (aside from rap itself, which is a form of EMI, per the latest rev of FCC title 47)?

Comment: Lol - that was embarrassing.  Is that why people down-voted it, or because of the actual question?

Comment: @NickAlexeev Just because the equipment is next to my laptop, and power cables.  Since I am dealing with audio I don't want there to be any audible humming or distortion.  Maybe it's just me being paranoid.

Answer (score 5):

It is unclear to me what the problem is that you are attempting to solve.  I have a suspicion that you are trying to eliminate a problem that doesn't really exist, but let me answer your question anyway.

If your problem is Firewire data errors than a ferrite device (rod, bead, or whatever) is unlikely to fix the problem.  It might, in fact, make things worse depending on exactly how you wrap the cable around the device.  But odds are that it just won't have any noticeable effect.

If the problem is noise from the computer getting into your Firewire analog audio interface then a ferrite device *might* help you, but is far from the ideal solution.  The physical size of the ferrite device is proportional to the frequency of interest that you are trying to filter out.  If your noise is around 60 Hz then the ferrite device would have to be somewhere between grapefruit and basket ball sized.  Even then, a ferrite device might not help you.

I've worked in the Pro-Audio field as an EE for a long time now and I can tell you that it is by far more effective to remove the source of the noise than to remove the noise after it has been added into the system.  If you are having a noise problem find the source of the noise and eliminate it-- don't mess around with filters and other kludge solutions that may or may not work.

Answer (score 2):

From comments in the O.P., it seems that the concern is that a PC (laptop) can be a source of EMI, and the audio equipment might be a victim.  In this context, yes, wrapping the cable around a ferrite rod would help reduce common mode EMI.

Threading a cable around a ferrite toroid might work even better.  The toroid would have to be fairly large for the cable to wrap without kinking.

But usually, the clamp-on ferrite cores are used.  [Like this one.](http://www.jameco.com/1/1/22133-zcat2035-0930a-cable-clamp-filter-emi-suppression.html)

If you're concerned that 60Hz hum is coming through the laptop, run the laptop on its battery.  See if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

FireWire is a digital protocol, so the data either comes out as a high or low voltage (0 or 1). As such, you don't really have to deal with interference problems like noise or capacitance. This is exactly the kind of snake-oil that HDMI cable manufacturers try to sell with gold-plated connectors and special shielding, none of which makes the slightest bit of difference to the digital data going down the line.

Comment: EMI affects data rates. If it can't sustain 1080p due to crappy cables or interference, hdmi will drop down to the next standard. It doesn't make a difference to the data, it does to the bandwidth and data rates available.

Comment: It isn't a question of whether the FireWire signal is affected, it's a question of the FireWire cable radiating or conducting signals that get into the low-level audio interface that he's trying to record with.

Answer (score 0):

The ferrite could reduce radiated emissions from the firewire cable, which are picked up by the audio frequency analog cables and equipment. Maybe the answers so far are mistakenly thinking in terms of susceptibility of the ethernet cable to interference when it's really a question about radiated emissions FROM the ethernet cable and susceptibility elsewhere in the system.